# get-buffer-window-list throws error in Emacs 24 if name not found

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have code which looks for an open window with one of three commonly used names, "*shell*", "*stata*", "stata".

I am running the following elisp code to check for each name:

```
(setq stata-win (get-buffer-window-list "*shell*"))
(if (eq (length stata-win) 0) (setq stata-win (get-buffer-window-list "*stata*")))
(if (eq (length stata-win) 0) (setq stata-win (get-buffer-window-list "stata")))

(car stata-win)
```

This previously worked, but the first line now triggers an error if a window with the name *shell* is not found. How can I test for the existence of an open window matching a name without triggering an error if the name is not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get-buffer-window-list`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffers-and-Windows.html) errors out only if the *buffer* does not exist.
If the buffer exists but is not displayed in any window, the function returns `nil`.

You can check for buffer existence using [`get-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html).

Thus, what you want is:

```
(defun get-buffers-window (buffer-names)
  (let (found buf)
    (while (and (null found)
                (setq buf (pop buffer-names)))
      (setq found
            (and (get-buffer buf)
                 (car (get-buffer-window-list buf)))))
    found))
(get-buffers-window '("*shell*" "stata" "*stata*"))
```

Note that for lists `foo` the forms

```
(if foo ...)
```

and

```
(if (< 0 (length foo)) ...)
```

are equivalent, but the former does not traverse the list (and thus faster) and also more idiomatic.

Comment: Excellent. The Emacs version switch was a red herring; I've removed it from the question.